# Ember CLI ember new fails on ember-cli-qunit

Tags: ember.js, npm, bower, ember-cli, bower-install

I've been trying to use Ember CLI to set up a new ember install, but the process keeps dying when trying to install ember-cli-qunit. I'm relatively new to using npm, bower, and ember so maybe this could just be an issue with me being dumb. Here is the dump I get when running

```
ember new webapp
```

[image]

I've been working on this for a few hours and can't really figure out how to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My guess is you ran `bower` as root at some point, and that changed the permissions in your home directory (as per the `EACCESS` line). Check those directories for their permissions, or simply change them back to your own user.

Comment: Ok, I'll check that out and see what happens. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That was definitely what happened. I had a few directories with incorrect permissions, so I was sudoing left and right with reckless abandon. If you want to create as an answer, I'll mark it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have ran bower as `root` at some point, and that would've changed the permissions of bower's cache files in your home directory (as per the error in the `EACCESS` line). Simply changing the permissions back to your own user (as `root` of course) should fix the problem.

Because of similar `sudo` problems driving me crazy (and the system's `nodejs` package being dated) I switched my setup to [`nvm`: node version manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) which installs everything to my own home directory instead and I never need to use `root` again for node-related installations.