# On creating a new ember app i am getting bower handlebars error

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

```
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
EACCES, unlink '/home/tanan/.cache/bower/registry/bower.herokuapp.com/lookup/handlebars_b644d'
Error: EACCES
 unlink '/home/tanan/.cache/bower/registry/bower.herokuapp.com/lookup/handlebars_b644d'
```

Unable to identify this particular error 
Also if anybody knows how to install ember-cli as a notmarl user (not a root user)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember CLI ember new fails on ember-cli-qunit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493360/ember-cli-ember-new-fails-on-ember-cli-qunit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you installing did you use 'sudo' or run as the root user? For me the installer failed and I had not choice then I experienced the same issue.

Try and reset the permissions back from root to your user with these commands:

```
sudo chown -R <you>:staff ~/.cache
sudo chown -R <you>:staff ~/.npm
```

Assume you are running OS X, modify accordingly.